# What happens to PhD applications that are missing recommendation letters?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

For your department and university specifically, do you still consider applicants when one or two of their letter writers never send in their letters?

Comment: Your question misses an opportunity to learn something. Why the restriction, unless this is a research question? The practice of the departments of a few users here doesn't give you anything actionable.

Comment: @Buffy Oh I just wanted some concrete examples.

Comment: It has happened before that an applicant was offered a PhD position although one of their recommender didn't send the letter, and it has happened before that an application was rejected because a recommender did not send a letter.

Comment: You may find useful to add information to the specific situation you have in mind to find anything actionable. There may be a polite way to remind the recommender to actually send the letter, or to ask them send it by email to the selection committee directly if the letter upload deadline has passed. There may be a way to change the recommender to another person in certain circumstances. Etc

Comment: @ojfewowmx I've just heard of people where their professors forgot to send in the rec letter in time. I'm deciding if I need to find a fourth recommender just in case, or if the phd committee will still review me if i miss a letter

Comment: Then, again, specific answers to the specific question you ask won't help you at all. Your case is specific, not general. Knowing how "other" departments handle it says exactly nothing about how those you apply to will. If you update the question you will get more useful help.

Comment: If you really want to know how you can be proactive in case one of your letter writers fails to write the letter, then ask that. [Vladhagen](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/176284/75368) gives some hints to a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, if a candidate is only missing one of three, we will still review the candidate. This accounts for the fact that recommenders are forgetful and not paid to write letters.

Candidates with no letters are not reviewed. Unless a candidate was internal, a candidate missing two letters is often not reviewed. The reality is that we have more quality candidates than open PhD spots usually.

In some special cases, if we can see that a candidate may have large potential, we might ask them to obtain another letter if they are missing two.

The bottom line for us at my institution is that a candidate might not get one letter because the person they asked to write one did not hold up their end of the deal. We will excuse that, all other things on their application being quality. But two or more letters? That tells us that the candidate themselves was not on top of things enough. That's not someone we want in our program.

---

I will add that I have occasionally seen applicants missing a letter because the writer never submitted the letter. **The applicant always let us know before hand that they were having issues contacting the writer.** If, for whatever reason, one of your recommenders is not submitting a letter, always contact the affected institutions. I've personally been known to give a few extensions for candidates that take initiative to let us know. In our system (and in most systems) the applicant themselves can see who has submitted letters and who has not.

Every application missing two or more letters was an abandoned application that had many other components missing as well.